# Image Centering with background-image:url vs. image tag

Tags: html, css, background-image, centering

I have a situation where I want to use a background image rather than an image tag. Image resizing for screen size is important here... the first example is what I want... the image resizes but stops when the height gets down to 300px.  Then if the screen size gets really narrow, the image stays centered and the ends get cropped on both sizes.  This can be achieved easily with `object-fit:cover`

The second div uses a background image and almost works, but when the screen gets narrow, I can't get the image centered. notice the image just gets cropped on the right size.

```css
.myimgtag {
width:100%;
height:auto;
min-height:300px;
object-fit:cover}



.mybackgroundimg {
background-image:url('https://www.panotools.org/dersch/StBp.JPG');
background-size:cover;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
min-height:300px;  
max-height: 2000px;
max-width: 2000px;
}
.mybackgroundimg:before {
content: "";
display: block;
padding-bottom: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img class='myimgtag' src='https://www.panotools.org/dersch/StBp.JPG'>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class='mybackgroundimg'></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the second image, have you tried [background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position)?

```css
.myimgtag {
width:100%;
height:auto;
min-height:300px;
object-fit:cover}



.mybackgroundimg {
background-image:url('https://www.panotools.org/dersch/StBp.JPG');
background-position: center;
background-size:cover;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
min-height:300px;  
max-height: 2000px;
max-width: 2000px;
}
.mybackgroundimg:before {
content: "";
display: block;
padding-bottom: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img class='myimgtag' src='https://www.panotools.org/dersch/StBp.JPG'>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class='mybackgroundimg'></div>
```